# can events be linked to bookings without creating custom fields?

Tags: civievent, civibooking

I have just activated civibooking and would like to link into an events calendar so that staff can see what resources have been booked for meetings etc.  I can pull the bookings into their own calendar which links to the booking, using booking id and primary contact, but can't see how to join this to the event - tried adding custom fields to event entity to take a booking id but wondering if will need to use rules, just hoping someone already done this before and could give some advice.

Many Thanks
Claire